# How to prove the coordinate of an inflection point of the function $f(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that the function $f(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has always an inflection point.

I already did that, but what I do not know how to do the second part:

> If it's graphic has 3 intersections with x, say $(x_1,0),(x_2,0),(x_3,0)$, prove that the coordinate $x$ of that inflection point is $\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$

Comment: You must have conditions on $a,b,c,d$, since otherwise $a = b = d = 0$ and $c = 1$ has no inflection point.

Comment: That is the only thing that the problem has, but you make a good point, what I did is that the 2nd derivate is equal to 6ax+2b and then equalized it to zero, then I assumed that a and b are not zero

Comment: You don't need to assume anything about $b$. However, it is necessary to assume that $a\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has three roots, then the function $f(x)$ can be represented as 
$$f(x) = k(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) = k(x^3-(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x-x_1x_2x_3)$$

Equating coefficients, you find $k=a$.

Taking the second derivative and setting equal to zero, you have:

$$f''(x) = 6ax-2a(x_1+x_2+x_3) = 0$$

$$x = \dfrac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$$